# Python re-order proportion inversely in a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, items

```
A = {0:{'a':1,'b':7, 'weight':0.6}, 
     1:{'a':5,'b':5, 'weight':0.3}, 
     2:{'a':4,'b':6, 'weight':0.1}}
```

I want to assign `inverse_weight` to each sub dictionary based on the inverse order of value `b`;

The order these b value is

```
   A[1]['b']  < A[2]['b'] < A[0]['b']
       5      <     6     <    7
```

Their weight are respectively

```
      0.6          0.3         0.1
```

Hence I need to inverse their weight:

```
      0.1          0.3         0.6
```

The desired A should be like

```
A = {0:{'a':1,'b':7, 'weight':0.6, 'inverse_weight':0.1}, 
     1:{'a':5,'b':5, 'weight':0.3, 'inverse_weight':0.6}, 
     2:{'a':4,'b':6, 'weight':0.1, 'inverse_weight':0.3}}
```

I don't know how to order these `b` and inversely apply to `inverse_weight`.

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The example is false because you said the weight of `A[1]` is 0.6, but in your dictionary it is 0.3

Comment: Not at all, I was simplifying the question and trying to do it  myseldf as well. I tried to solve it using lists. But I was really not sure it is the right way.

Comment: No, I intend to assign that, as I want to assign inverse_weight solely based on the value of b

Comment: You have to be clear: do you affect it solely based on the value of 'b' like you say, or with the weights in order of 'a' like you do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good excuse to use `zip`, `sorted`, and `reversed` in one method.

```
A = {0: {'a': 1, 'b': 7, 'weight': 0.6},
     1: {'a': 5, 'b': 5, 'weight': 0.3},
     2: {'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'weight': 0.1}}

# Make sorted list from A.items(), sorted by weight:
a_list = sorted(list(A.items()), key=lambda item: item[1]['weight'])

# Make a reversed copy of that list:
b_list = reversed(A_list)

A = {}
for a_item, b_item in zip(a_list, b_list):
    a_item[1]['inverse_weight'] = b_item[1]['weight']
    A[a_item[0]] = a_item[1]
```

Comment: No, I intend to assign 0.1  to 2, as I want to assign inverse_weight solely based on the value of b.

Comment: Garrett is right: the example is not correct, cf my comment on the question

Comment: Do you mean that you want the inverse weight of the element with the `k`th greatest `b` to be the weight of the element with the `k`th smallest `b`? If so change the lambda to `lambda item: item[1]['b']`. I am not sure what you are asking though.

Answer (score 0):

### Method

- Create a list of pairs `(A[id]['b'], id)`
- Sort this list
- Add the inverted weights in reversed order

---

### Code

```
lpairs = [(A[id]['b'], id) for id in A]
lpairs.sort()
for i in range(len(lpairs)):
    A[lpairs[i][1]]["inverted_weight"] = A[lpairs[len(lpairs)-1-i][1]]["weight"]
```

---

### Example:

For the data:

```
A = {0:{'a':1,'b':7, 'weight':0.6}, 
     1:{'a':5,'b':5, 'weight':0.3}, 
     2:{'a':4,'b':6, 'weight':0.1}}
```

This gives:

```
{0: {'a': 1, 'weight': 0.6, 'b': 7, 'inverted_weight': 0.3},
 1: {'a': 5, 'weight': 0.3, 'b': 5, 'inverted_weight': 0.6},
 2: {'a': 4, 'weight': 0.1, 'b': 6, 'inverted_weight': 0.1}}
```

---

*NB:*

The example you gave in your question isn't correct, because you say that the weight of `A[1]` is 0.6 but it is 0.3.

Comment: I don't know the list can be sorted based on the first tuple element, Thanks！

Comment: The list is sorted according to the first, then in case of equality to the second, etc

Comment: @LouisSugy You could create and sort `lpairs` at the same time: `lpairs = sorted((A[id]['b'], id) for id in A)` and you could shorten up the weight call slightly too: `A[lpairs[~i][1]]["weight"]`. https://bpaste.net/show/fd30a285fc59

Comment: I believe it's a bit more readable like that, and still not too long. I wouldn't write `A[lpairs[len(lpairs)-1-i][1]]["weight"]` in my own code but the OP seems to be a beginner (the question being rather basic).

Answer (score 0):

Your current listing of the desires weights is incorrect, as the weights for `[1, 2, 0]` should be `[0.3, 0.1, 0.6]`. However, you can use the code below to achieve the result when the correct weights, as listed above, are used:

```
A = {0:{'a':1,'b':7, 'weight':0.6}, 
 1:{'a':5,'b':5, 'weight':0.3}, 
 2:{'a':4,'b':6, 'weight':0.1}}
new_a = {a:b['weight'] for a, b in A.items()}
inverses = [new_a[c] for _, c in sorted([(A[i]['b'], i) for i in A], key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_inverses = dict(zip([c for _, c in sorted([(A[i]['b'], i) for i in A], key=lambda x:x[0])], inverses[::-1] if not len(inverses)%2 else inverses[len(inverses)//2+1:] +[inverses[len(inverses)//2]] + inverses[:len(inverses)//2]))
final_data = {a:{**b, **{'inverse_weight':final_inverses[a]}} for a, b in A.items()}
```

Output:

```
{0: {'weight': 0.6, 'b': 7, 'a': 1, 'inverse_weight': 0.3}, 1: {'weight': 0.3, 'b': 5, 'a': 5, 'inverse_weight': 0.6}, 2: {'weight': 0.1, 'b': 6, 'a': 4, 'inverse_weight': 0.1}}
```